# How can we delete an old question with no significant value?

Tags: support, old-questions, vote-to-delete, deleted-users, 10k-tools

I just wanted to vote to delete this question: [ASP.NET Editable Tree View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042614/asp-net-editable-tree-view/1042919), but for some reason I can't.

Okay, the question has upvotes, and that is probably the reason why, but OP has already left the building, so there is no one harmed. Also, there are no answers with upvotes and no accepted answer.

Should we as a community be able to delete this question without mod intervention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to delete it manually. The post is owned by a now-deleted user and has a negative score, so the system will auto-delete it after a while.

In fact, there are two excuses to auto-delete here; closed posts with negative score and no upvoted answers are also auto-deleted if there has been no activity on them for 9 days.

Because it was put on hold only yesterday, 10k+ users cannot vote to delete it just yet. 20k+ users can vote to delete it if it has a score of -3.

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> **By a user**:
>
> - Users with reputation >= 10k (more precisely, the “moderator tools” privilege; 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete questions **that have been closed/on-hold for 48 hours**. It takes three votes to delete; more if the question is popular, but ten votes at most.
>
> [...]
>
> **By the system:**
>
> - The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.
> - The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.

Comment: see also: [roomba criteria here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773): "Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:

    Closed more than 9 days ago
    Not closed as a duplicate
    Score <= 0
    Not locked
    No answers with a score > 0
    No accepted answer
    No pending reopen votes
    No edits in the past 9 days"

Answer (score 3):

It was only put on hold yesterday (29th June 2014).

Unless you have [20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and the question is at a score of -3 or less you have to wait 48 hours before you can vote to delete a question. This is to protect questions that could be improved from being deleted too quickly. This does mean you get situations like this, but the question will be deleted eventually either by users or by the automatic clean up processes that run periodically.

Comment: 20k+ users cannot vote to delete either until it has a -3 score.

Comment: "Voting to delete questions with a **score of -3 or lower immediately** after they are closed" ([Help Center > Privileges > trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user))

Comment: @gnat: it only got to -3 just now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773) :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It takes a MAN to delete this question.

Comment: What add on gives you those extra buttons above the `share | edit | reopen | ...` links?

Comment: @CanadianLuke: look for my profile on StackApps.com